# Adding a click handler to React children for methods on the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand passing a method down as a prop from a parent to child component.  For some reason I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around accessing a child components methods from props.children.

Hopefully my pseudo-code will make sense.

```
// ParentComponent
...
<ChildComponent>
  <button onClick={myMethod}></button>
</ChildComponent>
...


// ChildComponent
...
myMethod() {
  dosomething...
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
...
```

So in this example, I want to access 'myMethod' from a button that I pass to React children.  In my real world problem, the button was originally in the render method of childComponent, but I wanted more flexibility.  I think it can be done with refs, but I dont think thats the best way to do it, or if what I'm doing is even the right way to go about it.  Much thanks!

Comment: Why does `<button>` have to be a child of ChildComponent. If you render button inside ChildComponent you would not have this problem

Comment: @allenylzhou Correct, and thats how I had it originally.  I just found that I wanted to use two very different buttons in two locations in my app and thought this was smarter than trying to accommodate everything from within the child component.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There isn't any good way of doing this. You can use something like this. But, if you pass more than one child here, all of them will respond to this click handler! So, you should think of another logic to use this `Button`. As in this state, your `ChildrenComponent` is so generic.

So, what will your `Button` component do? You can create a component with this click handler and all other parts can be passed as props. Maybe in this way you can use it in multiple places.

```js
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <ChildComponent>
      <button>Click</button>
    </ChildComponent>
  </div>
);

const ChildComponent = ( props ) => {
  const handleClick = () => console.log( "clicked" );
  return (
    <div>
      { React.cloneElement( props.children, { onClick: handleClick } ) }
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Much thanks @devserkan, I agree and thats why I asked, because it didnt really feel right.  But I thought I miiiiight be missing something.  Your solution is neat though, I'll have to remember it!

Comment: You are welcome. I think you shouldn't remember it :) I don't see so much `React.clone` in other (much, much more experienced than me) people's code. Probably this is not the React way we should follow.

Comment: @devserkan Is it possible to use event.currentTarget in the handleClick function somehow?

Comment: @Fabioha, sure just use it like `const handleClick = e => {
    const { currentTarget } = e;
    console.log( "clicked", currentTarget)
  }`

Comment: @devserkan You are right, it does work when I do it with the example code above. But in my code it doesn't pass the event value, so I can't get the currentTarget. Do you have any idea why this could be?

Comment: No, sorry. But, feel free to ask a new proper question about that.

Comment: what if i wish to 'merge' both events? meaning that if the child passed his own onClick event i will first trigger his event and then my custom event

Answer (score 1):

```
function Child(props, ref) {
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        onClick: () => {
            //Do something
        }
    }));
    return <div>child</div>;
}

Child = forwardRef(Child);


function Parent(props) {
    ChildRef = useRef()
    //here you can call it fom parent 
    ChildRef.current.focus()
    return (
        <Child ref={ChildRef} />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this situation using [render props](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), which is when a React component expects a prop that is a function which returns JSX.

```
type Props = {
  render: () => React.ReactNode;
};
```

To render the prop, you call it like a function inside your component's returned JSX.

```
const Component = ({ render }: Props) => {
  return <>{render()}</>;
};
```

And since it's just a function, you can pass any arguments you want to it, so the consumer can access them.

```
type TableProps = {
  rows: TableRow[];
  renderRow: (row: TableRow) => React.ReactNode;
};

const Table = ({ rows, renderRow }: TableProps) => {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {rows.map((row) => <tr key={row.id}>{renderRow(row)}</tr>)}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const rows = useGetTableRows();

  return (
    <Table
      rows={rows}
      renderRow={(row) => (
        <>
          <td>{row.name}</td>
          <td>{row.age}</td>
        </>
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

In the context of your example, the code would look like this:

```
type ChildComponentProps = {
  renderButton: (onClick: () => void) => React.ReactNode;
};

const ChildComponent = ({ renderButton }: ChildComponentProps) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('clicked');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {renderButton(handleClick)}
    </div>
  );
};

const ParentComponent = () => {
  return (
    <ChildComponent 
       renderButton={(handleClick) => (
         <button onClick={handleClick}></button>
       )} 
    />
  );
};
```